# How can I find out what Selenium WebDriver is waiting for?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a Selenium WebDriver (Java) test case that sometimes fails and throws a `TimeoutException`. A lot of diagnostics (Build info, System info, Capabilities etc) is included in the exception but none of it says anything about what it was waiting for.

```
WebDriver webDriver = ...;
webDriver.get(pageUrl);  // TimeoutException here (occasionally)
```

Is there a way, using the Selenium WebDriver API, to find out what the driver was waiting for?

Selenium WebDriver Java: 2.43.0
Firefox: 32.0

Comment: Well, it depends. Can you share your code?

Comment: @Jon, You can enable the web-driver log & see what is going on? did you try that way?

Comment: @VinothS: Interesting, I haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until full page loading; after that perform any operation on Web Element go through below code

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Then handle Web Element.